Scroll Functionality in Appium 2.5
Since touch gestures have been removed in the recent versions of Appium, you may be facing trouble with scrolling in iOS. The below code works for Android but not for iOS:
The below code works for Android but can't find the solution for android
await driver.execute("mobile:scroll", {
strategy: "toVisible",
selector: "~cars news-cars-view-more-button",
});
I'm expecting a solution to scroll on iOS device
Tech stack- Node.js and appium

Have you tried mobile:swipe in downward direction instead of mobile:scroll

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();

scrollObject.put(“direction”, “down”); // up, left, right

scrollObject.put(“element”, ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());

js.executeScript(“mobile: swipe”, scrollObject);

